# Change payment gateway option based on cart total in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

For my woocommerce shop, i have this filter in functions.php. It force 3DS with "woocommerce Stripe Gateway" plugin.

```
add_filter('wc_stripe_require_3ds','__return_true');
```

It work great.

I would like this filter to be active only for order over 50€.

I tried with this but it doesn't work, the order is validated without 3DS.

```
    $minsecure = 50;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $total = $order->get_total();

    if($total>$minsecure) { 
          add_filter('wc_stripe_require_3ds','__return_true');
    }
```

I also try to get the cart amount instead of the order amount, but I don't know which one to get for the filter to be active between the time of the "order" click and the confirmation page.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for this to check if the price of the order is over 50

```
if( WC()->cart->subtotal > 50 )
```

So the snippet would look like

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_updated', 'wc_stripe_require_3ds', 90);
function wc_stripe_require_3ds ( $cart ){
    if( WC()->cart->subtotal > 50 ) {
        add_filter('wc_stripe_require_3ds','__return_true');
    }
}
```

Have a try.

Comment: It works perfectly, I am impressed with your responsiveness, it is extremely pleasing, I had been looking for the solution for several hours.

Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome to SO, for all questions about WooCommerce @LoicTheAztec is the guy but if I can help sometime, I'm glad about it ;-)